# How to do custom validation on input without nesting form tag through [formControl]?

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, angular2-forms

I am getting this error while using  [formControl] on input where no nested  tag and FormGroup present.

In my component .ts file I am initializing formControl as new FormControl();

I am getting this error core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot create property 'validator' on string 'XYZABC'

Comment: Share the typescript code where you are creating the `FormControl`

Comment: This is on HTML Code : 
<input type='number' [formControl]="numberValidator" (change)="isNumberChanged()" [(ngModel)]="numberAmount">

On TypeScript :

I am initializing with 
numberValidator= new FormControl();
this.formError = this.numberValidator.setValidators([FormValidatorFactory.createNumericNotEqualsValidator('errorcode', 155)]);

So here I am creating my own custom validator which match the entered number with this 155 and return error code or null.... However this above error is gone now..getting another issue now where I am getting formcontrol is undefined error in validtor